# Should I declare permission "com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" when using Alarm Manager in Android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-permissions

I've seen many tutorials using `AlarmManager`, some did declare `com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM` and some didn't.
When should I declare it and when I shouldn't ?
My app use is setting an `Alarm` to go off and execute `onReceive()` of the receiver at specific time.

Comment: Try it. If it doesn't work without the permission, add it. If it does, don't add needless permissions. It should only take a couple minutes to figure it out either way.

Comment: It works without, but I.E. I started getting reports that the alarm is not firing in API 19 , so I suspect this behavior. (I'm using `SetExact()` instead of `Set()` and yet...)

Comment: According to the documentation, you only need the permission for "setTime".

Comment: @Christine it says that you need SET_TIME permission to setTime, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setTime(long)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to declare "com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" to use the AlarmManager. That permission is needed when you use AlarmClock.